# Cast enum definition name to string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

If i have enum like that:

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        Element1 = 1,
        Element2,
        Element3,
        Element4 
    }
```

How could i cast `MyEnum` to `String()` in the code

I know that i may cast any `Enum` value to sting like that `MyEnum.Element1.ToString()`, but how I may cast Enum definition/name to string?

I want to do something like that :

`MyEnum.ToString()`

Comment: try `MyEnum.GetType().Name` for a variable of type MyEnum.  Or `typeof(MyEnum).Name` for the type itself

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case I think you may very well be better off using a display name attribute like the example [here](http://www.ytechie.com/2008/05/creating-user-friendly-strings-for-enum-values.html).  The enum string representation often isn't quite what you'd want to display and you'd need to update code in various places if you wanted that string to change.

Comment: +1 Enums are often misused.  If you need a string value from it, just use an object.

Answer (score 1):

As @shsmith said, use:

```
typeof(MyEnum).Name
```

But unlike he said, don't use:

```
MyEnum.GetType().Name
```

Since MyEnum isn't static, and hence can't invoke that method.
You can use `GetType()` on a specific element though, like so:

```
MyEnum.Element1.GetType().Name //=MyEnum
```